# Почему на Ubuntu 14.04 греется система больше чем на Win7?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, производительность, cpu

Здравствуйте. Есть ноутбук Acer Aspire V5-131-10074G50akk 
На вин 7 вентилятор периодически отключается в работе и ноут ощутимо не греется. Когда поставил убунту 14.04, то вентилятор не вырубается пока ноут не выключится. 
С термопастой и железом все ок. Драйвера все что надо поставил. Процессор хоть и загружен на 2-3%, но имеет температуру от 47 до 53 градусов.

```
laptop@laptop-V5-131:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +53.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +52.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +46.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Частота процессора следующая

```
laptop@laptop-V5-131:~$ cpufreq-info 
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1.60 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 1000 MHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 1.60 GHz.
                  The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1.60 GHz:4,66%, 1.50 GHz:0,32%, 1.40 GHz:0,34%, 1.30 GHz:0,72%, 1.20 GHz:0,42%, 1.10 GHz:0,33%, 1000 MHz:0,26%, 900 MHz:0,44%, 800 MHz:92,52%  (2183)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1.60 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 1000 MHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 1.60 GHz.
                  The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1.60 GHz:9,07%, 1.50 GHz:1,40%, 1.40 GHz:0,86%, 1.30 GHz:0,97%, 1.20 GHz:0,90%, 1.10 GHz:0,76%, 1000 MHz:0,88%, 900 MHz:0,94%, 800 MHz:84,21%  (6380)
```

Апплетом, что сверху справа(забыл название) ставлю частоту до 800 МГЦ, но всеравно проц греется и вентилятор работает, что сумарно уменьшает автономность.

Можно ли как то уменьшить нагревание кремниевой железки в данном случае?? С этой убантой пробую работать около недели, но никак не пойму в чем же беда с перегревом проца даже в состоянии ничегонеделания. Люди добрые, помогите)

Comment: 53 градуса - это в рамках нормальной рабочей температуры для проца.

Comment: Даже больше - до критической температуры полсотни градусов. Что там в новой убунту не знаю. Ищите настройку кулеров.

Comment: laptop-tools ставил?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию

Answer (score 0):

*Ubuntu* сам по себе — дистрибутив не из легких, с его прожорливым *unity desktop*.

Оптимизация хуже, чем у *Win*, намного хуже. Этот вопрос поднимался уже ни раз на «хабре»: батарею *Ubuntu* сжирает быстрей (*Win* 4-5 часов, *Ubuntu* 2-3 часа).

А про нагрев: в принципе, 50 градусов — это нормальная температура для процессора, но в ноутбуках на *Win*, при работе без использования ресурсоемких приложений, температура может падать до 35 градусов.

Все данные подкреплены использованием *Ubuntu 14.10* параллельно с *Win7* на собственном ноутбуке.

Comment: При всем уважении, но без подкрепленных данных Вас могут заминусовать, или даже могут побить. Было бы любопытно взглянуть на подобное сравнение на реальных данных